# Using Docker with official Progress OpenEdge RDBMS images

Tags: docker, rdbms, openedge, progress-db

I found out that Progress has provided [official docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/oe-db) for their RDBMS.

I managed to pull the following image:

```
docker pull store/progresssoftware/oedb:12.2.3_adv-ent
```

I tried following the [instructions](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-database-docker-container/page/Download-an-OpenEdge-database-Docker-container-image.html) to set it up, but they ask you to [edit files inside the image?](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-database-docker-container/page/Examine-the-contents-of-the-build-directory.html).

I'm not totally sure if they want me to only use the `zip` versions of the images or pull the images directly from the docker hub? Or is the idea to create my own `Dockerfile` where I use these as base images, and then set and create the required files and changes there? I couldn´t find anyone using these images in the web.

**Could somebody provide me with example ´docker run´ command or ´Dockerfile´ to use these things?**

Answer (score 0):

## docker load vs docker run

You use `docker load` when you have docker image in archive format. Sometimes you do not want to `push` image to public places and you do not have `private repository`.
In this case you can do `docker save`. This command generates archive of your container. Then you can send this archive to private ftp.

To get this image you need:

1. Download image
2. Run `docker load`

When your image is uploaded to `docker repository` and you have rights to get it, you can use `docker pull` command. This is preferred command.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to run this enterprise tool, but they provide instruction here: https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-database-docker-container/page/Run-an-OpenEdge-database-Docker-container-image.html

So example is:

```
docker run -d -p <database_server_port>:<database_server_port> -p <database_minport>-<database_maxport>:<database_minport>-<database_maxport> -e DB_BROKER_PORT=<database_server_port>
 -e DB_MINPORT=<database_minport> -e DB_MAXPORT=<database_maxport> <custom_image_name>
```

you may use it as:

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -p 5435-5440:5435-5440 -e DB_BROKER_PORT=5444
 -e DB_MINPORT=5435 -e DB_MAXPORT=5440 store/progresssoftware/oedb:12.2.3_adv-ent
```

UPD: correct port forwarding syntax

Answer (score 0):

beware that these images are for development and testing purposes only - they are not supported for production

> The custom container images can then be used to bring up and dispose of database instances on demand for the purposes of incrementally building and testing OpenEdge applications